Postman Integration Github, Checkout Repo
I have created a postman API and integrated with GitHub, it is working fine and I pull and push changes with my account.
I have now shared the repository with my colleagues but they can't connect to the repo because it says repo has been connected to a different team.
Is it possible to checkout repo in Postman with a different account in a different team?
